# Javascript SUBSTR

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic string value "**radio_3_***".

Like:

1 - radio_3_5

2 - radio_3_8

3 - radio_3_78

4 - radio_3_157

5 - radio_3_475

How can I pick the **radio_3** part.

Comment: Right, what have you tried so far to accomplish this?

Comment: Go through this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp

Comment: You can get the substring in numerous ways. Use your noggin'!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic regular expression

```
var str = "radio_3_5";
console.log(str.match(/^[a-z]+_\d+/i));
```

And how the reg exp works

```
/       Start of reg exp
^       Match start of line
[a-z]+  Match A thru Z one or more times
_       Match underscore character
\d+     Match any number one or more times
/       End of Reg Exp
i       Ignores case
```

Or with split

```
var str = "radio_334_1234";
var parts = str.split("_");
var result = parts[0] + "_" + parts[1];
```

Or even crazier (would not do)

```
var str = "radio_334_1234";
var result = str.split("_").slice(0,2).join("_");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just take your string and use javascript method match

```
myString = "radio_334_1234"
myString.match("[A-Za-z]*_[0-9]*")

//output: radio_334
```

[A-Za-z]* Will take any number of characters in upper or lower case

_         Will take the underscore

[0-9]*    Will take any number of characters from 0 to 9

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str = 'radio_3_78';
var splitStr = str.split('_');
var result = splitStr[0] + '_' + splitStr[1];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7faag7ug/2/

Comment: Why would you split the same thing twice?

Comment: I thought it looked better as a one-liner, but you're right. I corrected it.

Answer (score -3):

Use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop), like below.

```
"radio_3_475".split("_").pop(); // = 475
```